# Rewrite URL for Profile Page

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

How do I use **.htaccess** to rewrite:

```
mysite.com/profile/[username]
```

go to:

```
mysite.com/profile.php?id=[username]
```

I don't want to have to reload the page just change the URL to make it look good.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the htaccess rule that should get you started:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule profile/(.+) profile.php?id=$1
```